# JPA sorting not sorting in reverse order correctly

Tags: spring-boot, sorting, spring-data-jpa, pagination

I have a Book Repository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository
    extends CrudRepository<Book, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Book> {}
```

I build a Pageable as follows:

```
Pageable pageable =
        PageRequest.of(offset / limit, limit, Sort.Direction.DESC, "bookName");
```

Now by calling the repository:

```
Page<Book> bookPage = bookRepository.findAll(bookSpecification, pageable);
```

I get this list back:

```
Test Book
Test Book
Test Book
Test1
Test 0906
```

If I'm not wrong, when using descending order, Test1 should come before Test Book.
and when testing the code, it fails:

```
assertThat(getBookNameNameList(jsonNode)).isSortedAccordingTo(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: You are trying to compare the sort order of your database with a comparator. Those are different things and will likely sort in different orders. You are also assuming that the list you parse from JSON is still in the same order.